# Why i have "Nan" value from the loop which is summing up the table column

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, html-table, sum

I have a problem with this loop. I want to sum up the values from the table, but i have NaN value from this code. Should i change something or is there any other solution to sum up?

```
function sumUpWallet() {
    var walletTable = document.getElementById("usersCrypto");
    let sumVal = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < (walletTable.rows.length - 2); i++) {
        const tableData = walletTable.rows[i].cells[3];
            if (tableData && tableData.textContent) {
                const value = parseFloat(tableData.textContent);
                if (!isNaN(value)) {
                sumVal = sumVal + value;
                };
            };
    }
    console.log(sumVal);
    document.getElementById("sumDol").innerHTML = sumVal.toFixed(2);
};
```

Table is dynamic, after click the button another row is added. For example it can looks like this:

[image: Screenshot page]

[image: Example table accesibility]

Answer (score 1):

Problem is when you do:

```
console.log(walletTable.rows[i].cells[3]);
```

you get the follow result back `<td>19271.71</td>` instead of the figure 19271.71 for the first result of i

To fix this do add .textContent to the parseFloat like below

```
sumVal = sumVal + parseFloat(walletTable.rows[i].cells[3].textContent);
```

Added:

It looks like you are accessing data outside the range of the table. You need to do some validation to ensure what you are reading is valid before adding it to sumVal.

```
const tableData = walletTable.rows[i].cells[3];
if (tableData && tableData.textContent) {
    const value = parseFloat(tableData.textContent);
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
       sumVal = sumVal + value;
    }
}
```

Added an example that proves the above code works.

```js
function sumUpWallet() {
    var walletTable = document.getElementById("usersCrypto");
    let sumVal = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < (walletTable.rows.length - 2); i++) {
        const tableData = walletTable.rows[i].cells[3];
            if (tableData && tableData.textContent) {
                const value = parseFloat(tableData.textContent);
                if (!isNaN(value)) {
                sumVal = sumVal + value;
                };
            };
    }
    console.log(sumVal);
    document.getElementById("sumDol").innerHTML = sumVal.toFixed(2);
};

sumUpWallet();
```

```html
<table id="usersCrypto" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
        Name
    </td>
    <td>
        price
    </td>
    <td>
        Amount
    </td>
    <td>
        Header
    </td>
   <tr>
   
   
   <tr>
    <td>
        Bitcoin
    </td>
    <td>
        19271.71 
    </td>
    <td>
        1
    </td>
    <td>
        19271.71 
    </td>
   <tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td>
        Ethereum
    </td>
    <td>
        1070.11 
    </td>
    <td>
        2
    </td>
    <td>
        2140.23
    </td>
   <tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        
    </td>
    <td>
        PLN
    </td>
    <td>
        DOL$
    </td>
   <tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
       Summary Value 
    </td>
    <td>
        
    </td>
    <td id="sumDol">
        
    </td>
   <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have console error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')". I also added accesibility, Can problem be with rowgroup section and with the fact that it is a dynamic table?

Comment: Updated answer to handle undefined

Comment: Ok, i updated the code but now I always have zero in Summary Value

Comment: Updated again with working code that confirms it works. You may need to provide HTML markup if it doesn't work for you.